# Using Webview in an Andengine

Tags: android-intent, webview, andengine

Hi I want to make a game but I need to load a webpage in Webview for it, is there a way to use webview in a Scene ( like the gamescene )... or is there a way to start a New Intent (which include the Webview) in scene ? 
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You do not need nothing special thing!

```
public void openGoogleHomepage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("https://google.com"));
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //error occurred
    }

}
```

if you have got problem, try to open in UI thread:

```
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            openGoogleHomepage()

        }
```

Comment: First, thx and second ehm yeah i how can use this in a Scene ? I tried to add it into my andengine scene but the startActivity(intent); part is red underlined :/ and i cant import sth. can you help me pls?